# Selecionar notas que devem ser impressas

Tags: c, c++, if

Preciso imprimir apenas as notas acima de >=6, em que lugar do código coloco o `if` ou alguma outra instrução?

Já tentei e não consegui achar o local correto.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 50

struct aluno {
    char nome[50];
    int matricula;
    float nota;
};

void imprime(aluno v[], int num);

int main(void) {
    // Declara um aluno
    aluno alunos[MAX];

    alunos[0].matricula = 12014432;
    alunos[0].nota = 7.5;
    strcpy(alunos[0].nome,"Fulano");
    alunos[1].matricula = 13022301;
    alunos[1].nota = 5.9;
    strcpy(alunos[1].nome,"Sicrano");
    alunos[2].matricula = 11024122;
    alunos[2].nota = 4.0;
    strcpy(alunos[2].nome,"Beltrano");
    alunos[3].matricula = 11014120;
    alunos[3].nota = 6.1;
    strcpy(alunos[3].nome,"Huguinho");
    alunos[4].matricula = 11024012;
    alunos[4].nota = 8.0;
    strcpy(alunos[4].nome,"Zezinho");
    alunos[5].matricula = 11014117;
    alunos[5].nota = 3.5;
    strcpy(alunos[5].nome,"Luizinho");

    imprime(alunos, 6);

}

void imprime(aluno v[], int num) {
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {

        cout << "Mat.: " << v[i].matricula << endl;
        cout << "Nome: " << v[i].nome << endl;
        cout << "Nota: " << v[i].nota << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qual a parte que está imprimindo o que você quer? Atualmente imprime a nota de todos os alunos, certo?

```
    cout << "Mat.: " << v[i].matricula << endl;
    cout << "Nome: " << v[i].nome << endl;
    cout << "Nota: " << v[i].nota << endl;
```

Esta, certo?

Então o `if` deve encapsular toda ela e nada mais que ela. O trecho que faz varrer todo o vetor é este:

```
for (i=0; i<num; i++) {

    cout << "Mat.: " << v[i].matricula << endl;
    cout << "Nome: " << v[i].nome << endl;
    cout << "Nota: " << v[i].nota << endl;
}
```

Então ficaria:

```
for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
    if (v[i].nota >= 6) {
        cout << "Mat.: " << v[i].matricula << endl;
        cout << "Nome: " << v[i].nome << endl;
        cout << "Nota: " << v[i].nota << endl;
    } 
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Filter.cpp).

Comment: Eu quase consegui havia colocado if (nota[i]>=6), muitissimo obrigado novamente.

Comment: Para imprimir a nota você usou `v[i].nota`, para verificar qual é a nota, não tem porque ser diferente. A nota é a nota, ela não pode ser de um jeito em um lugar e de outro em outro lugar. neste caso você está pegando o campo `nota` do elemento indicado por `i` do vetor `v`.